# How to animate several heatmaps in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, gganimate

I have 30 heatmaps in the form of square matrices. Each heatmap is linked to a date and I would like to create an animation transitioning from one heatmap to the next based on the date. I am using `gganimate` in `R` in order to do so and I am encountering some problems. Let me show an example with some random data

```
# GENERATE RANDOM DATA. 30 3X3 MATRICES STORED IN list_matrices
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, ggplot2, av, gganimate)

list_matrices = list()
for(i in 1:30){list_matrices[[i]] = matrix(runif(9), nrow=3)}

# PUT ALL THE MATRICES TOGETHER INTO A TIBBLE AND 
# DO A PIVOT LONGER IN ORDER TO USE GGPLOT

for(i in 1:length(list_matrices))
{
  tmp_result = list_matrices[[i]] %>%  as_tibble() %>% 
    mutate(rowname = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
           frame = i) %>%
    pivot_longer(-c(rowname, frame), names_to = 'colname')
  if(i == 1)
  {
    df_result = tmp_result
  } else{
    df_result = rbind(df_result, tmp_result)
  }
}
```

This is the dataframe that I will plot:

```
> df_result
# A tibble: 270 x 4
rowname frame colname  value
<chr>   <int> <chr>    <dbl>
1 a         1  V1      0.456 
2 a         1  V2      0.716 
3 a         1  V3      0.316 
4 b         1  V1      0.724 
5 b         1  V2      0.766
```

And I create the plot:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df_result, aes(x = rowname, y = colname, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 3))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="red", limits=c(0, 1))

p + transition_time(frame) +
  labs(title = "Date: {frame_time}")
```

I am having **three problems here**

1. I am outputing this into a video, but regardless the number of matrices in list_matrices (this is, regardless the number of heatmaps I have) the video always lasts 10 seconds, so transition is too fast. Is there a way to increase video duration?
2. The video quality is poor. Is there a way to increase quality?
3. I am including the value of the variable in the heatmap, and I have set `geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 3)))` to round the number of decimals, but some of the heatmaps in the video show way more than 3 decimals. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your three problems could be addressed as

1. change `fps` to 1 to slow down (modify further to slow it down).
2. save as `png` to get better video quality
3. wrap your round with `as.character()` in the label.

   `p <- ggplot(data = df_result, aes(x = rowname, y = colname, fill = value)) +  geom_tile() +  geom_text(aes(label = as.character(round(value,3)))) + scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="red", limits=c(0, 1))`

   `pp <- p + transition_time(frame) + labs(title = "Date: {frame_time}")`

   `animate(pp, fps=1, dev="png")`